# Why can't I alter the height of a TextBox control in the windows forms design view?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I have a new project. I drop a textbox control on it. I open up the properties window, and I can change the height and hit enter or click out of the box and it will update the designer, but when I try to change the height it resets back to the default value. Why is that? I had the same issue with a Label, but I turned off AutoSize and it allowed me to modify the values. Is there some property I can turn off to be able to modify the Height of a textbox in the design view? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 sp1. I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2008. I am new to Windows forms.

Comment: Make the textbox multiline and it will allow you to set the height.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to set `TextBox.Multiline` property as `true` .

```
TextBox1.Multiline = true;
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I dind't realize it was actually bound to the Font-size though. If i change the font-size it alters the textbox size which makes perfect sense.  I just didn't get it right off the bat. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Checking *Multiline* will allow to resize but it also allows **enter(return)** key in the textbox.

The Height of a non-Multiline TextBox is fixed by the size of the Font.

Reduce to textbox **Font** size, the TextBox will *resize* automatically.

Comment: What if I want to have padding inside?

Comment: Padding like font padding? Like the space between the textbox line and first character?

Comment: The space between the TextBox border and the text itself, I think it's not possible right (unless you work it around with a panel or smth)?

Comment: @nick Try this.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903083/textbox-padding)

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but it's got to be so haaard? Why couldn't they just add a TextBox padding property? :(

Comment: Ya, there is nothing easy making font padding in the textbox. However, you can try making a user control and inherit a textbox and make your own textbox. That's hard too but if your pad length is like space then you can design and use your own textbox easily.

Answer (score -1):

To resize height, you will find a drop-down menu. In here, check *multiline*.

And you can't resize labels at all. They automatically scale to the text.

Comment: You can resize labels though. Just set the Label's property named AutoSize to False.